# se reinician los items de mi pagina a pesar de guardarlos en el localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, html5, arraylist, local-storage

Estoy tratando de mejorar el código de mi primer proyecto, un `to do list` y lo que quiero hacer es guardar los items en el `localStorage`, de forma que al refrescar el navegador, estos no se borren o reinicien.

Guardo los datos en un objeto dentro de una lista y con un único id para cada item; el nombre que como valor tiene el `itemValue`, que es donde guardo el valor del input.

El problema es que los datos se guardan en el `localStorage`, pero al reiniciar la pagina se borran.

Por favor si me explican que es lo que sucede y también agradecería si me dicen si a simple vista mi código es legible y si se entiende o mejor dicho si es un `código limpio`.

```js
"use strict"
//date function
const dateElement= document.getElementById("date");
const options= {
    weekday:"long",
    month:"short",
    day:"numeric"
}
const today= new Date();

dateElement.innerHTML= today.toLocaleDateString("en-US",options);

const list= document.getElementById("list");
const input= document.getElementById("input");
const normalButton= document.getElementById("normal");
const finishedTask= document.getElementById("done");
const unfinishedTask= document.getElementById("not-done");
const refreshBtn = document.getElementById("refresh-btn");

document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{ if(event.keyCode === 13) addToDo() });

function addToDo(){
  
    refreshBtn.addEventListener("click",() => refreshPage());

    event.preventDefault();

    let itemValue= input.value;

    if(itemValue === "" || itemValue === null) return alert("Por Favor escribe algo en tu lista");
    
    const itemNew= document.createElement("li");
    const deleteButton= document.createElement("button");
    const para = document.createElement("p");
    const editButton= document.createElement("button");
    const checkButton= document.createElement("button");
    const buttonsContainer= document.createElement("div");

    itemNew.appendChild(buttonsContainer);
    buttonsContainer.classList.add("buttons");
    
    //creating text
    para.classList.add("text");
    const text= document.createTextNode(itemValue);
    para.appendChild(text);
    
    //item
    itemNew.classList.add("item");
    itemNew.appendChild(checkButton);           
    itemNew.appendChild(para);
    list.appendChild(itemNew);

    //check-buttton
    checkButton.classList.add("checkbox");
    checkButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-circle fa-lg"></i>`
    checkButton.value= "not-checked";

    //edit-button
    editButton.classList.add("edit");
    editButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-edit"></i>`
    buttonsContainer.appendChild(editButton);
    
    //delete-button
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`
    buttonsContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
    
 
    //checkbox button
    checkButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{

        if (checkButton.value ==="not-checked") {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","checked");
            checkButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i>`
            
        } else {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","not-checked");
            checkButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-circle fa-lg"></i>`
        }
        checkButton.classList.toggle()
        para.classList.toggle("completed");
    });

    //edit button
    editButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            let editText= prompt("Inserte aqui el texto a cambiar ...");
            para.innerHTML=editText;
        }
    );

    //delete button
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", ()=> list.removeChild(itemNew) );
         
    //normal button
    normalButton.addEventListener("click", ()=> itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block") );

    //finished-task button
    finishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        checkButton.value==="checked" ? itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block")
        :itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
    });

    //unfinished-task button
    unfinishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        checkButton.value==="not-checked" ? itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block")
        :itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
    });

    //AQUI ES DONDE ESTA EL PROBLEMA
            
    let lists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item.list")) || [];
    let data = createDataList(itemValue);
    lists.push(data);
    save();
    
    function save(){  
        localStorage.setItem("item.list", JSON.stringify(lists));
    }

    function createDataList(name){
        return {id: Date.now(), name: name,};
    }

    function refreshPage(){
        localStorage.clear();
        location.reload();
    }

    input.value = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/09faf5376a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
           
            <i class="fas fa-sync-alt" id="refresh-btn"></i>
         
            <div class="title-container">
                <h1 class="title">To Do List App</h1>
                <h2 class="ferre">By Fxrree</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div class="date" id="date"></div>
            
            <div class="functionalities">
                <button id="normal" class="normal">NORMAL</button>
                <button id="done" class="done">DONE</button>
                <button id="not-done" class="not-done">NOT-DONE</button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list" class="list"></ul>
        </div>

        <div class="add-item">
            <input type="text" class="input" id="input" placeholder="Add something to do">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg" id="button" onclick="addToDo()"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: La carga de elementos desde _localStorage_ está dentro de la función `addToDo()` y debería estar fuera, probablemente dentro de una función que se ejecute automáticamente después de cargar el DOM, ya sea dentro de `window.onload = function() { ... };` o, mejor aún, `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... });`

Comment: Pero como podría actualmente hacerlo en el código porque si si pongo el localStorage fuera de la función addToDo(), porque no puedo obtener información desde afuera de la función principal. y si pudieras poner una respuesta publica por si otros usuarios tienen la misma duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es definir `lists` en contexto global para poder acceder fuera de `addToDo()`. En cuanto cargue el DOM obtienes lo que hayas guardado en `localStorage`, agregándolo a `lists`.

Ahora solo falta agregarlo al HTMl, usando la función `addToDo` y enviando cada elemento como parámetro. Por supuesto, se modificó la función para poder recibirlo.

Al crear el contenido, solo hay que verificar:

- Si se proporcionó un parámetro: Tomar desde aquí valores para agregar a HTMl y omitir la parte donde se agrega a las listas o volver a guardar
- Si no se proporcionó parámetro: Tomar valor desde input y hacer todo el proceso normalmente

```js
"use strict"
//date function
const dateElement= document.getElementById("date");
const options= {
    weekday:"long",
    month:"short",
    day:"numeric"
}
const today= new Date();

dateElement.innerHTML= today.toLocaleDateString("en-US",options);

const list= document.getElementById("list");
const input= document.getElementById("input");
const normalButton= document.getElementById("normal");
const finishedTask= document.getElementById("done");
const unfinishedTask= document.getElementById("not-done");
const refreshBtn = document.getElementById("refresh-btn");

document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{ if(event.keyCode === 13) addToDo() });

// Necesitas tener la lista disponible desde aquí
// Y no se puede usar const porque se va a modificar
let lists = [];
// Obtener desde localStorage al cargar todo el DOM
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    lists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item.list")) || [];
    // Agregar en HTML los elementos encontrados
    lists.forEach((item) => addToDo(item));
});

function addToDo(fromList){
  
    refreshBtn.addEventListener("click",() => refreshPage());

    event.preventDefault();
    // Obtener valor desde localStorage si fue proporcionado o desde input
    let itemValue= (fromList) ? fromList.name : input.value;

    if(itemValue === "" || itemValue === null) return alert("Por Favor escribe algo en tu lista");
    
    const itemNew= document.createElement("li");
    const deleteButton= document.createElement("button");
    const para = document.createElement("p");
    const editButton= document.createElement("button");
    const checkButton= document.createElement("button");
    const buttonsContainer= document.createElement("div");

    itemNew.appendChild(buttonsContainer);
    buttonsContainer.classList.add("buttons");
    
    //creating text
    para.classList.add("text");
    const text= document.createTextNode(itemValue);
    para.appendChild(text);
    
    //item
    itemNew.classList.add("item");
    itemNew.appendChild(checkButton);           
    itemNew.appendChild(para);
    list.appendChild(itemNew);

    //check-buttton
    checkButton.classList.add("checkbox");
    checkButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-circle fa-lg"></i>`
    checkButton.value= "not-checked";

    //edit-button
    editButton.classList.add("edit");
    editButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-edit"></i>`
    buttonsContainer.appendChild(editButton);
    
    //delete-button
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`
    buttonsContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
    
 
    //checkbox button
    checkButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{

        if (checkButton.value ==="not-checked") {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","checked");
            checkButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i>`
            
        } else {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","not-checked");
            checkButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-circle fa-lg"></i>`
        }
        checkButton.classList.toggle()
        para.classList.toggle("completed");
    });

    //edit button
    editButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            let editText= prompt("Inserte aqui el texto a cambiar ...");
            para.innerHTML=editText;
        }
    );

    //delete button
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", ()=> list.removeChild(itemNew) );
         
    //normal button
    normalButton.addEventListener("click", ()=> itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block") );

    //finished-task button
    finishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        checkButton.value==="checked" ? itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block")
        :itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
    });

    //unfinished-task button
    unfinishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        checkButton.value==="not-checked" ? itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block")
        :itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
    });

    //AQUI ES DONDE ESTAba EL PROBLEMA
    // No agregar a la lista si proviene de localStorage
    if(!fromList) {
        let data = createDataList(itemValue);
        lists.push(data);
        save();
    }
    
    function save(){  
        localStorage.setItem("item.list", JSON.stringify(lists));
    }

    function createDataList(name){
        return {id: Date.now(), name: name,};
    }

    function refreshPage(){
        localStorage.clear();
        location.reload();
    }

    input.value = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/09faf5376a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
           
            <i class="fas fa-sync-alt" id="refresh-btn"></i>
         
            <div class="title-container">
                <h1 class="title">To Do List App</h1>
                <h2 class="ferre">By Fxrree</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div class="date" id="date"></div>
            
            <div class="functionalities">
                <button id="normal" class="normal">NORMAL</button>
                <button id="done" class="done">DONE</button>
                <button id="not-done" class="not-done">NOT-DONE</button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list" class="list"></ul>
        </div>

        <div class="add-item">
            <input type="text" class="input" id="input" placeholder="Add something to do">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg" id="button" onclick="addToDo()"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Genial. Muchísimas gracias por tu explicación.